# Why is this forloop updating all previous values?

Tags: matlab

```
for i = 1:p
    X_poly(:, i) = X .^ i;
end
```

Iteration 1:

```
  -15.9368         0         0         0         0         0         0         0
  -29.1530         0         0         0         0         0         0         0
   36.1895         0         0         0         0         0         0         0
   37.4922         0         0         0         0         0         0         0
  -48.0588         0         0         0         0         0         0         0
   -8.9415         0         0         0         0         0         0         0
   15.3078         0         0         0         0         0         0         0
  -34.7063         0         0         0         0         0         0         0
    1.3892         0         0         0         0         0         0         0
  -44.3838         0         0         0         0         0         0         0
    7.0135         0         0         0         0         0         0         0
   22.7627         0         0         0         0         0         0         0
```

---

Iteration 2:

```
   -0.0159    0.2540         0         0         0         0         0         0
   -0.0292    0.8499         0         0         0         0         0         0
    0.0362    1.3097         0         0         0         0         0         0
    0.0375    1.4057         0         0         0         0         0         0
   -0.0481    2.3097         0         0         0         0         0         0
   -0.0089    0.0799         0         0         0         0         0         0
    0.0153    0.2343         0         0         0         0         0         0
   -0.0347    1.2045         0         0         0         0         0         0
    0.0014    0.0019         0         0         0         0         0         0
   -0.0444    1.9699         0         0         0         0         0         0
    0.0070    0.0492         0         0         0         0         0         0
    0.0228    0.5181         0         0         0         0         0         0
```

For some reason... the second iteration, it's changing the values if X_poly(:,1) which... it shouldn't because I changed `X.^1` to `X+1` and it did exactly what I expected it to do...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most likely you just have forgotten to show us the whole output. Probably, in the second one there was a `1.0e+03 *` in the beginning.

You are just dealing with display differences, but the numbers are the same.

Try executing `format long g` and then running this again, youll realise the numbers are the same. [Read more](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/format.html)